# issue with Xrm.Page.data.entity.save("saveandclose")

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

When i open an opportunity form and from there i have opened an opportunity product, but when i comes back to project and click on save and close it returns back me to opportunity product page (which i have opened last) instead of opportunity list page.

So, i have make custom function on save and close button and write code as following :

```
function SaveAndClose() 
{
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save("saveandclose")
}
```

but issue remain same.

Please anyonve can you help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed issue by following code:

```
function SaveAndClose()
{
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
    if (parent.opener != undefined)
    {
        window.parent.close();
    }
    else
        Xrm.Page.ui.close();

}
```

Hope this help !!!!